# How debug unexpected error while everything seems right?

Tags: r, include, markdown, truetype

{r setup,include=FALSE}

Give this Error:

> Error: unexpected symbol in "  {r setup"

why?

Comment: It would be extremely helpful to include the script that produced this error.

Comment: I just started by this and didn't add anyscript yet.

Comment: It's very unclear what you are doing at the moment? Are you using RStudio? Are you trying to create an RMarkdown document? What exactly triggers this error?

Comment: 1) Yes 2) Yes 3)I really don't know . I just started by this code!

Comment: This is the error you would get if you typed the line directly into your R console. That's not how you write an Rmarkdown document. You need to start a new R Markdown document in the menu and when you want to run it press the 'knit' button.